# i'm trying to use the below formula(image attached) to get first set of numbers in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7W9Z.png)

but with this code iam not getting the right number if the first number is from 1 to 12.
After 12 iam getting the right answer.

Comment: first set of numbers?  The numbers before the `-` or before the first letter?

Comment: I get that you are too lazy to paste your sample data into a code block but are you really too lazy to put the formula into one as well?

Comment: Help yourself with this array formula `=LEFT(C1,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(C1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(C1))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(C1))))))`

Comment: Maybe you just need this: `=VALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND("-",C1)-1))`